# UITableViewCell show image from UIImage

Tags: ios, uitableview

I creating tableView with list of file names and thumbnails. I don;t have a problem with file name, but when i passing UIImage array to tabeView, I getitng error, Here is a code:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrayColletionImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

arrayColletionImages image i get from:

```
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:0.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];
[player stop];
[arrayColletionImages addObject:thumbnail];
```

All UITableViewCell code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrayColletionImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);
return cell;
}
```

Comment: what is the error you getting?

Comment: in which line you are getting error ?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrayColletionImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

Comment: 2013-05-13 13:09:06.340 iphone[1141:18e03] -[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa8e3b80
2013-05-13 13:09:06.341 iphone[1141:18e03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa8e3b80'

Comment: can you `NSLog(@"Image Name: %@",[arrayColletionImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);`

Comment: 2013-05-13 13:12:23.202 iphone[1189:18e03] Image Name: <UIImage: 0xa905250>
2013-05-13 13:12:23.203 iphone[1189:18e03] Image Name: <UIImage: 0xa8a5430>
2013-05-13 13:12:23.203 iphone[1189:18e03] Image Name: <UIImage: 0xab31250>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use this one. You are accessing the image name from the array, But you already store an `UIImage` object in this array, So there is no need  to call `imageNamed:`
So write this line

```
cell.imageView.image = [arrayColletionImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Have you got your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Array may not contain the UIImage Objects.Log the value in the array

`<UIImage: 0xa8a5430>` in log means it is an UIImage object and in the `cellForRow` code you are using it again as.

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrayColletionImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

`UIImage imageNamed:` expect an **NSString not UIImage** so 
remove this

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrayColletionImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Try this in code

```
[cell.imageView setImage:[arrayColletionImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: Thanks, sorted. It works with this code too. Just encase, are you from LTU ?